# Facebook description on like box not showing on Facebook wall

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, sharing

I have a video blog website where you can like a video. The problem is that if you click the fb-like button, the correct title, description and photo pops up. After you submit a message to post on your Facebook wall, the description disappears.

I have the OG set to:

```
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />   
<meta property="og:title" content="Father Of The Month? | TimeJacker.com" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.timejacker.com/videos/31397-father-of-the-month.html" />
<meta property="og:description" content="...again one from Poland :)" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.timejacker.com/uploads/__images/large/father%20of%20the%20month.jpg" />
```

I also have a description tag with the same value as my `og:description`. 
The problem is it won't happen every time.

(I cannot add a screenshot of the FB-wall view, because of my reputation, but it shows a title, image and the content a user typed. But not the description.)

Does anyone know the problem?

You can view it on: http://www.timejacker.com/videos/31397-father-of-the-month.html

Answer (score 0):

try changing the name of your description tag. Though facebook will fetch description from the og:description, it would be nice not to have tags with the same name. Try renaming the tag. (Not the og:description)